# html-docx-js is not abe to apply external css class styles when it creates docx file

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, docx

Using html-docx-js module, I am able to covert html content into docx format. However I am running into an issue where most of my css is loaded externally and html-docx-js does not apply any of its styles.

Simplified code sample:

```
const html = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/page.css"></head><body><div className={bold}>I am bold!</div></body></html>'
saveAs(htmlDocx.asBlob(html), 'bold.docx');
```

It was suggested to use juice library, however that did not work either.

Would anyone know if there is a work around to get html-docx-js to load external css when creating docx file?

Comment: Does it help if you use an absolute URL (http: //www.something.com/styles/page.css) instead?

Comment: not specifically as html-docx-js just embeds the css url into word document and my websever is local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit a research I found a working solution to my problem(s):

There is a module called juice, which allows to apply specified css inline.

Juice needs a copy of css, which I had to separetely load.

Also since html-docx-js can only read only first css style definition within an element, I had to slightly adjust css and html to accommodate that.

Final code looks like this:

```
    import htmlDocx from 'html-docx-js/dist/html-docx';
    import saveAs from 'file-saver';
    const juice = require('juice');

     let getIndex = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.requests('GET', '/styles/index.css')
        .then(data =>
          data.text().then(css => {
            resolve(css);
          })
        )
        .catch(error => reject(error));
    });

    getIndex
      .then(css => {
        let html =
          '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head lang="en"><style></style>' +
          '<meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Report</title></head><body>' +
          this.report.innerHTML +
          '</body></html>';

        html = juice.inlineContent(html, css);
        let docx = htmlDocx.asBlob(html);
        saveAs(docx, 'report.docx');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **CSS class** in the **head** tag, but you must select the **element tag** and the **classname** together.

It looks like this:

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">
    div.MyCustomClass {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
<div class="MyCustomClass">
...
</div>
</body>
```